# hdparm : SG_IO: questionable sense data, results may be incorrect

Tags: linux, disk, ssd, hdparm

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I would like to know if my system supports the trim command for my SSD. So I typed the following thing :

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/nvme0n1 | grep TRIM
```

and the result is

```
SG_IO: questionable sense data, results may be incorrect
```

In another forum, they said that we have to add a line to the kernel boot parameter, but in which path can I find it ?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this a bit today and while I don't have what I'd call a great answer I did land on [this bit of code](https://github.com/Distrotech/hdparm/blob/master/sgio.c#L304-L308)

```
if (io_hdr.driver_status != SG_DRIVER_SENSE) {
        if (sb[0] | sb[1] | sb[2] | sb[3] | sb[4] | sb[5] | sb[6] | sb[7] | sb[8] | sb[9]) {
            static int second_try = 0;
            if (!second_try++)
                fprintf(stderr, "SG_IO: questionable sense data, results may be incorrect\n");
            ...
```

I'm testing on an AWS i3.8xl where when running `hdparm --verbose -I /dev/nvme0n1` I can see that `driver_status=0x0` which would seem to indicate either sense isn't supported for the drive, or maybe you just can't see it from the guest VM.

For my own purposes, I'm probably gonna just go with http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ssd-instance-store.html#InstanceStoreTrimSupport and AWS support to see what I should be using regarding drive TRIM settings.

At least according to this doc, the non-zero value reported here should indicate TRIM support.

```
root@...:~# cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/discard_max_bytes
2199023255040
```

Comment: Oh, I did also just come across https://sourceforge.net/p/hdparm/bugs/69/ which seems to confirm my suspicion that due to either device or driver constraints hdparm can't be used when the driver status doesn't indicate support for this operation.

Comment: And a final follow up after a lot of fio testing is that TRIM on i3.8xl is probably a bad idea. Very poor disk performance while TRIM is running on those drives.